# Display one time welcome screen titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am working on titanium [new to this platform], I am using Titanium 3.1.0 version  Alloy.

display one time welcome screen.

welcome screen name is IndexWindow next screen is LoginWindow.

when i relaunch the application it need to show loginWindow. not IndexWindow[welcome Screen].

Where i need to do changes for this?

@ all 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you'll need to persist the info by using properties like this :

```
if(Ti.App.Properties.hasProperty('loggedBefore')) {
    // open login window
} else {
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('loggedBefore', '1');
    // open indexWindow
}
```

Comment: I did the persist  the loginWin, but where i need to load it when application launches next time.

Comment: persist a flag. loggedBefore in the example. Please check this link to understand more about Ti.App.Properties: [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)